# Números ordinais

Tags: python

Olá, estou iniciando na programação e estou estudando Python. Realizando um exercício consegui chegar no resultado esperado. No entanto,  quando tento realizar o mesmo programa convertendo a lista para INT, não funciona. Apresenta erro de saída, mesmo add a class int no comando Print. Alguém pode me tirar essa dúvida?

```
lista_numeros = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

for lista in lista_numeros:
    if lista == '1':
        print(lista + 'st')

    elif lista == '2':
        print(lista + 'nd')

    elif lista == '3':
        print(lista + 'rd')

    else:
        print(lista + 'th')
```

Comment: Qual seria o código problemático? Esse?

Comment: Acabei de testar o seu código e não deu nenhum erro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você transformar a lista para `int` precisará converter a `linha` para `string` antes de concatenar e imprimir. Também mudar os valores de comparação nos comandos `if`. A conclusão é que você pode converter, só não faz sentido porque o código ficará mais confuso. Segue como ficaria:

```
lista_numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for lista in lista_numeros:

    if lista == 1:
        print(str(lista) + 'st')

    elif lista == 2:
        print(str(lista) + 'nd')

    elif lista == 3:
        print(str(lista) + 'rd')

    else:
        print(str(lista) + 'th')
```

Comment: Eu estava fazendo de uma forma totalmente diferente, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: A linha `str(lista).split(',')` não faz sentido e não precista estar no código. O problema do OP é resolvido com a conversão da variável `lista` para `str` no momento do `print`.

Comment: Grato Gabriel, editei a minha resposta conforme o seu comentário.